# servicestack System.Runtime.Serialization pre-load error

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Why getting this error ?

```
 Error  12  Unknown build error, 
'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' 
because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, 
dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the    
ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'   WpfApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project refereneces 
need to add System.Runtime.Serialization names solved the problem